# How to set filter to generate a custom EXCELl with DRF renderer-xlsx

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Good afternoon I have the following query, I am using the library
Renderer-xlsx of DRF to generate an excel, I download it when passing the respective url, the question is that I want to apply filter to this excel, so that I do not download everything that is in the database, but what I I indicated in the filter.

In summary: I have a download button in the frontend (ANGULAR), I press it, I indicate the filter that for example in the excel only comes the records that meet this condition (EquipoOriggen = C65CAN01) I pass it as a request and return get the excel

[image]

As you see download, but all the records, and I need it with filter

My serializer

```
class InterfaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
# Las siguientes lineas me permiten agregan campos de otros modelos al modelo en cuestion que estoty serializando a traves de llaves foraneas.
#Se le agrega la propiedad de read_only=True para que el campo no sea editable.
    EquipoOrigen = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.nombre',read_only=True)
    PuertoOrigen = serializers.CharField(source='id_PuertoOrigen.nombre',read_only=True)
    LocalidadOrigen=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.localidad',read_only=True)
    CategoriaOrigen=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.categoria',read_only=True)
    EquipoDestino = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.nombre',read_only=True)
    PuertoDestino = serializers.CharField(source='id_PuertoDestino.nombre',read_only=True)
    LocalidadDestino=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.localidad',read_only=True)
    CategoriaDestino=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.categoria',read_only=True)
    Vendedor=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.vendedor',read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=Interfaces
        fields=('id_interface','id_EquipoOrigen','EquipoOrigen','id_PuertoOrigen','PuertoOrigen','LocalidadOrigen','CategoriaOrigen','Vendedor','estatus','etiqueta_prtg','grupo','if_index','bw','bw_al','id_prtg','ospf','description','id_EquipoDestino','EquipoDestino','id_PuertoDestino','PuertoDestino','LocalidadDestino','CategoriaDestino','ultima_actualizacion',) 


class PostPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size=10
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

#Funcion Para El Filtro del Modelo Interfaces.

class InterfacesFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    EquipoOrigen=filters.CharFilter(field_name='id_EquipoOrigen__nombre',lookup_expr='contains')
    LocalidadOrigen=filters.CharFilter(field_name='id_EquipoOrigen__localidad',lookup_expr='exact')
    Vendedor=filters.CharFilter(field_name='id_EquipoOrigen__vendedor',lookup_expr='exact')
#Declarando el Meta    
    class Meta:
        model=Interfaces
        fields= ['EquipoOrigen','LocalidadOrigen','Vendedor']


class InterfacesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset=Interfaces.objects.all()
    serializer_class=InterfaceSerializer
    pagination_class=PostPageNumberPagination
    filter_class=InterfacesFilter
```

My class for excel download

```
class MyExampleViewSet(XLSXFileMixin, ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Interfaces.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InterfaceSerializer
    renderer_classes = (XLSXRenderer,)
    filter_class=InterfacesFilter
    filename = 'my_export.xlsx'
```

**UPDATE**

To know how to solve my problem and generate an EXCEL with DRF, I recommend going through the following URL:

[How to capture parameters from a URL in Django Rest Framwrek to process it in a view [SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57347512/how-to-capture-parameters-from-a-url-) in-django-rest-framwrek-to-process-it-in-a

Answer (score 0):

You can read an xls file simply with panda library.

First you receive your file in serializer class:

```
myXlsFile = validated_data['myxlsFile']
```

then read it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('myxlsFile', sheet_name='Sheet1')
```