# How to capture parameters from a URL in Django Rest Framwrek to process it in a view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django. I am using Django Rest Framework as an Api Rest but I need to generate an endpoint or URL that is going to be passed from the frontend (Angular) to get a custom excel.

The question is that for example, I will pass the following URL: `127.0.0.1:8000/app_prtg/descarga/P79COL01`
and I want to capture the value `P79COL01` that would be my filtering value to get my excel file, with this parameter I process in a DRF view and I can generate the excel

P79COL01 is the value associated to the EquipoOrigen field of my serialized model Interfaces –

My Url

```
127.0.0.1:8000/app_prtg/descarga/P79COL01
```

My Url Definition

```
router.register(r'descarga',MyExampleViewSet)
```

My Models

```
class Equipos(models.Model):

    id_equipo=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    vendedor=models.CharField(max_length=10,default='S/A',blank=True)
    ip_gestion=models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='Ipv4',default='0.0.0.0')
    tipo=models.CharField(max_length=8,default='S/A',blank=True)
    localidad=models.CharField(max_length=5,default='S/A',blank=True)
    categoria=models.CharField(max_length=10,default='S/A',blank=True)
    ultima_actualizacion=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Equipos'

class Puertos(models.Model):

    id_puerto=models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    ultima_actualizacion=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table='Puertos'

class Interfaces(models.Model):

    id_interface=models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id_EquipoOrigen=models.ForeignKey(Equipos,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='equipo_origen')
    id_PuertoOrigen=models.ForeignKey(Puertos,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='puerto_origen',
                                      null=True,blank=True)
    estatus=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    etiqueta_prtg=models.CharField(max_length=80,null=True,blank=True)
    grupo=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    if_index=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    bw=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    bw_al=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    id_prtg=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    ospf=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    id_EquipoDestino=models.ForeignKey(Equipos,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='equipo_destino')
    id_PuertoDestino=models.ForeignKey(Puertos,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='puerto_destino')
    ultima_actualizacion=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table='Interfaces'
```

My serializers

```
class EquipoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=Equipos
        fields=('id_equipo','nombre','vendedor','ip_gestion','tipo','localidad','categoria','ultima_actualizacion',)

# class NestedEquipoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

#     class Meta:
#         model = Equipos
#         fields = ('id_equipo', 'nombre', 'localidad', 'categoria',)        

# Serializando los Datos del Modelo Equipo_Interface(Registros)

class PuertoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=Puertos
        fields=('id_puerto','nombre','ultima_actualizacion')

class InterfaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
# Las siguientes lineas me permiten agregan campos de otros modelos al modelo en cuestion que estoty serializando a traves de llaves foraneas.
#Se le agrega la propiedad de read_only=True para que el campo no sea editable.
    EquipoOrigen = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.nombre',read_only=True)
    PuertoOrigen = serializers.CharField(source='id_PuertoOrigen.nombre',read_only=True)
    LocalidadOrigen=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.localidad',read_only=True)
    CategoriaOrigen=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.categoria',read_only=True)
    EquipoDestino = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.nombre',read_only=True)
    PuertoDestino = serializers.CharField(source='id_PuertoDestino.nombre',read_only=True)
    LocalidadDestino=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.localidad',read_only=True)
    CategoriaDestino=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.categoria',read_only=True)
    Vendedor=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.vendedor',read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=Interfaces
        fields=('id_interface','id_EquipoOrigen','EquipoOrigen','id_PuertoOrigen','PuertoOrigen','LocalidadOrigen','CategoriaOrigen','Vendedor','estatus','etiqueta_prtg','grupo','if_index','bw','bw_al','id_prtg','ospf','description','id_EquipoDestino','EquipoDestino','id_PuertoDestino','PuertoDestino','LocalidadDestino','CategoriaDestino','ultima_actualizacion',)
```

my view to generate the excel and where I should process what comes in the URL and get the value of P79COL01

```
class MyExampleViewSet(XLSXFileMixin, ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Interfaces.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InterfaceSerializer
    renderer_classes = (XLSXRenderer,)
    filter_class=InterfacesFilter
    filename = 'my_export.xlsx'
```

**Update:** Thanks to the help of the friend Arpit Svt I was able to solve with his answer, in this way it was possible to create a filter to generate my excel according to the parameter that happened to him, in my case I wanted to print for the EquipoOrigen property, which is a string , and not because of its id. It is a very easy way to generate excel report by consuming a REST API with Django Rest Framework. The updated code is as follows:

```
class MyExampleViewSet(XLSXFileMixin, ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = InterfaceSerializer
        renderer_classes = (XLSXRenderer,)
        filename = 'my_export.xlsx'

        def get_queryset(self):
                queryset = Interfaces.objects.all()
                name = self.request.query_params.get('name', None)
                if name is not None:
                    queryset = queryset.filter(id_EquipoOrigen__nombre=name)
                return queryset
```

The url that happened

http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_prtg/descarga/?name=P79COL01

The Excel I get

[image]

Comment: If you want to filter data by `P79COL01` you should pass it in query params like `127.0.0.1:8000/app_prtg/descarga/?name=P79COL01`

Comment: what is P79COL01?

Comment: P79COL01 is the value associated to the EquipoOrigen field of my serialized model Interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter data by P79COL01 you should pass it in query params like `127.0.0.1:8000/app_prtg/descarga/?name=P79COL01`, you can access query_params using `self.request.query_params` inside the view.

So you can override the get_queryset method to return filtered queryset.

Here is the updated code

```
class MyExampleViewSet(XLSXFileMixin, ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = InterfaceSerializer
    renderer_classes = (XLSXRenderer,)
    filter_class=InterfacesFilter
    filename = 'my_export.xlsx'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Interfaces.objects.all()
        name = self.request.query_params.get('name', None)
        if name is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(name=name)
        return queryset
```

Comment: It worked, just what I was looking for. But I have a doubt, within the parameters for the function, I had to place some field that belonged to the Interfaces model, such as Id_EquipoOrigen, the question is that I want instead of placing the id_EquipoOrigen (which is a foreign key in the model interfaces of the model Team) I want to place is the property or attribute "nombre" of Equipo Model, as is the EquipoOrigen field in the InterfacesInterfaceSerializer serializer

Comment: I already resolved. What should be done using the double underline syntax syntax, in this case name is replaced by id_EquipoOrigen__nombre, where id_EquipoOrigen is the foreign key and name the property as such with which we want to check. I hope it serves many more people.